# Selecting repeated values of a multi-index level with .loc

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

First lets suppose I have a pandas dataframe with a single index. If I use `.loc[]` to select index 'A' twice, it will return a dataframe with index 'A' repeated twice:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3], index=['A','B','C'], columns=['Col_1'])
df_1

    Col_1
A   1
B   2
C   3

df_1.loc[['A','A','B']]

    Col_1
A   1
A   1
B   2
```

Now lets suppose we have a dataframe with a multi-index. If I use `.loc[]` to select index 'A' twice, it will return a dataframe with index 'A' included only once:

```
ix = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B', 'C'], ['foo', 'bar']], names=['Idx1', 'Idx2'])
data = np.arange(len(ix))
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=ix, columns=['Col_1'])
df_2

           Col_1
Idx1 Idx2       
A    foo       0
     bar       1
B    foo       2
     bar       3
C    foo       4
     bar       5

df_2.loc[['A','A','B']]


           Col_1
Idx1 Idx2   
A    foo       0
     bar       1
B    foo       2
     bar       3
```

Is there any way to select repeated values of a multi-index level using `.loc`?

Comment: Since A is duplicate itself , you have two A for the first level ...

Comment: `pd.concat(df_2.loc[x] for x in ['A','A','B'])`?

Comment: is the tile ordering of the foo/bar level important or will it suffice to have [(A, foo) (A, foo) (A, bar) (A, bar)]?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an additional method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pandas tries to keep the levels of a `MultiIndex` unique.  When you use `loc` with a list that refers to values of the first level of the `MultiIndex` it will keep things unique.  If you want something different, you'll need to be explicit and use tuples.

```
specific_index_values = (
    [('A', 'foo'), ('A', 'bar')] * 2 +
    [('B', 'foo'), ('B', 'bar')]
)

df_2.loc[specific_index_values, :]

           Col_1
Idx1 Idx2       
A    foo       0
     bar       1
     foo       0
     bar       1
B    foo       2
     bar       3
```

---

#### `pandas.concat`

I find this distasteful but...

```
pd.concat([df_2.loc[[x]] for x in ['A', 'A', 'B']])

           Col_1
Idx1 Idx2       
A    foo       0
     bar       1
     foo       0
     bar       1
B    foo       2
     bar       3
```

Comment: I think this is a subject which can use some more explanation and you probably have the knowledge. MultiIndex is definitely a topic which can be confusing imo and is one of the downsides of the pandas API if you ask me.

Comment: It can be confusing and there are bugs in addition to just being normal confusing... But I'll defend them to the end.  They provide the mechanism to make dataframes as many-dimensional as you need.  They are chief reason why Panel was deprecated (imo) as you don't need a 3-D "dataframe" if you have MultiIndex.  AND, the chief reason why Pandas dataframe is better than R's dataframe.... but yes, many explanations would be useful.